# Boto, amazon S3 and Cloudfront distribution

Tags: python, video-streaming, boto, amazon-cloudfront

I'm developing an app where users can upload videos. The backend sends them to S3 and for playback I'm generating an auto expire url from S3 which I have to pass on to Cloudfront for streaming back to user.

I'm using `boto` in `Django` and I have 80% of the code working until the part where I have to chain cloudfront. The private S3 url is generated and works just fine.

```
s3_conn = S3Connection(
    aws_access_key_id = settings.CONFIG.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key = settings.CONFIG.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    is_secure = True
)
video_url = s3_conn.generate_url(
    60,
    'GET',
    bucket = settings.CONFIG.AWS_VIDEO_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
    key = self.premium_video_url,
    force_http = True
)

origin = cloudfront.origin.S3Origin( "{}.s3.amazonaws.com".format( settings.CONFIG.AWS_VIDEO_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ) )
cloudf = boto.connect_cloudfront( settings.CONFIG.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.CONFIG.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY )
stream_distributions = cloudf.get_all_streaming_distributions()

if not len(stream_distributions):
    distro = cloudf.create_streaming_distribution( origin = origin, enabled = True, comment = 'Video streaming distribution' )
else:
    distro = stream_distributions[0]

return distro.create_signed_url(
    video_url,
    expire_time = int( time.time() + 3000 ),
    private_key_file = self.premium_video_url
)
```

Lines with problems:
`distro = stream_distributions[0]` returns a `StreamingDistributionSummary` instead of a real distribution object or whatever is needed: `'StreamingDistributionSummary' object has no attribute 'create_signed_url'`

Also the return code probably misses something.

I'm having all sorts of problems finding a decent example since `boto` seems to have changed a lot lately and all existing examples are no longer working.

Comment: There should be a method called ``get_distribution`` on the ``StreamingDistributionSummary`` object that will return the actual ``StreamingDistribution`` object.

Comment: yes but it requires an id which I don't know where to get from.

Comment: No, this is the one I was referring to (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html#boto.cloudfront.distribution.StreamingDistributionSummary.get_distribution).  It doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: got it working yesterday but your answer was the right one: `distro = stream_distributions[0].get_distribution()`